# waiting for pages to be filled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

the contained of my pages are dynamic, then how to display the page if the page contained is complete, if not I wait message appears.

i used jquery mobile.

```
    $("#A1").live('pageshow', function()
        {
// code for fill the page
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the [`pagebeforeshow` event](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html). Your code would be executed before the page is shown:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#A1', function(ev){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: can i write `$("#A1").live('pagebeforeshow', function(){//myc code});`

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't recommend it, as `live` is deprecated as of jQuery v1.7

Comment: ok thank you but when i use your code i have same result like my code. page changed befor fill all contain